# Parse.Com - HTTP method in cloud code, how do I wait for the response

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my parse cloud code, the HttpRequest in beforeSave is getting executed successfully but the code blows through before I have had time to parse the response and determine whether I want to return a `response.success()` or a `response.error()`.

I know I am missing something here, any input, ideas from the community here would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function (request, response) {    
    var user = request.object;
    var key = user.get("recaptcha");  

        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=<ITS A SECRET>&response=' + key,
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            var status = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text).success;
            console.log(status);
            if (status === false) {
                response.error();
            } else {
                response.success();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want to process the JSON content?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for getting in touch, I am just looking to extract the status value from the json response,  and if the status is true then save the data (via response.success()) into the user table else do not save the data. (response.error())

Comment: So you're getting the status out? Or do you need to change to ['success'] to index into the JSON object

Comment: That is correct, I am getting status from the json response,  problem is that it blows through before the response has been returned from Google recaptcha.

Comment: I mean, do you see the status printed in the log? The only other thing to do is use a promise instead of the simple callback. Are you sure the http request doesn't return an error you aren't handling?

Comment: I just need some way to wait for the response to come back before I proceed

Comment: I do see the status in the log, but I see it in a totally different order..it's all asyn, I see log entries for afterSave and then I see the status from beforeSave

Comment: No errors from the http response, the json is structured with 200: data, the data is coming back but it is blowing past...need to wait for the response, parse and then proceed.

Comment: It should wait until you call the response handler, do things you don't want get saved is key rather than log order necessarily

Comment: I agree, just not sure why it is not waiting, at least it looks like it is not waiting based on log. The call to Google is successful, then I try to parse the response but it blows through, I suspect it is asynchronous and this is why I am seeing in the logs aftersave logic mixed in with beforesave

Comment: Hmm.. This is weird.. BeforeSave will pass when you call `response.success()`. Have you tried `Promise` method?

Comment: Indeed..which is why I think the success on the http is blowing past and not parsing the response,  I will try promises and report back.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, bouncing ideas helped me to figure it out..turned out the asyn was blowing my code away.  I should be using return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest( ...         This link was useful...[link]https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-make-a-https-request-in-parse-cloud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working...Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() is asynchronous, here is the solution that worked for me,  hope it helps someone else.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function (request, response) {    
    var user = request.object;
    var key = user.get("recaptcha");  
    if (!request.object.existed()) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },                
            url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=<ITS A SECRET>&response=' + key,
            body: request,
            success: function(httpResponse) {
                var status = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text).success;
                if (status === false) {
                    response.error();
                } else {
                    response.success();
                }
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
                response.error(httpResponse);
            }  
        });
        }
       });
```

Comment: You can also use Parse Promises.