# parse.com JavaScript signup security

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

How can fake signups be prevented as the javascript api keys are visible in the client source code? I've read the class-level permissions and ACLs, but for signups, the user is required to enter and save their username and password to begin with.
Someone could easily keep adding fake users/data to someones parse.com app. I know it can happen on other systems, but for parse.com, the developer has to watch out for incurring data costs and not to get over the request per second. So how can it be prevented? Surely there is some mechanism to stop this and if it parse.com should not charge the develop if their own system has no easy way to prevent.

If you try to run this html signup from desktop in browser you can keep adding users:-
**Edit**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reg</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.5.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 body {
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 40px;
 }
 /* Custom container */
 .container-narrow {
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 700px;
 }
 .container-narrow > hr {
     margin: 30px 0;
 }
 /* Main marketing message and sign up button */
 .jumbotron {
     margin: 60px 0;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .jumbotron h1 {
     font-size: 72px;
     line-height: 1;
 }
 .jumbotron .btn {
     font-size: 21px;
     padding: 14px 24px;
 }
 .marketing {
     margin: 60px 0;
 }
 .marketing p + h4 {
     margin-top: 28px;
 }
</style>

<script>
Parse.initialize("Your-Application-ID they got from your app/website", "Your-Javascript-Key they got from your app/website");
//#################################################################################################
$(document).ready(function() {

    Parse.User.logOut();

    $("#submit").click(function(){  // capture the click


            //parse 
                                    var user = new Parse.User();
                                    user.set("username", $('input[name=username]').val());
                                    user.set("password", $('input[name=password]').val());
                                    user.set("email", $('input[name=email]').val());

                                    // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
                                    //user.set("phone", "415-392-0202");

                                    user.signUp(null, {
                                      success: function(user) {
                                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.

                                        var name= user.get("username");
                                        alert(name);

                                      },
                                      error: function(user, error) {
                                        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                                        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                                      }
                                    });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-narrow">

        <hr>

        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active in" id="home">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6 offset1 well">
                        <legend>
                            <h5>Sign Up</h5>
                        </legend>
                        
                            <input type="text" id="username" class="span6" name="username" placeholder="User ID"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" id="email" class="span6" name="emsil" placeholder="User Email"><br><br>
                            <input type="password" id="password" class="span6" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <hr>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign Up</button>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask

Comment: Yes, I did thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addressed the fake signups on our site by using the google recaptcha v2 https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html#advanced-security that I added to my signup page and with some server side cloud code, steps:

1. Register  your domain at google recaptcha, you get two keys, a key site and a secret key. Google recaptcha will only work on the specified domains and local host.

   - Site key goes in your HTML.
   - Security key is used to communicate on the server cloud code with google.
   - make sure you use google recaptcha v2
2. Integrate the site key and recaptcha widget into your html, there are many examples on the web on how to do that.
3. When the user submits recaptcha,  web site gets a response from google. If google's machine learning recaptcha is suspicious of you, then it will prompt a challenge to prove that you are a human.
4. After you pass the challenge, google sends a response token to your web site.
5. On your Parse signUp, send the token along with the User details to your cloud code.
6. In cloud code beforeSave trigger, send the token to google along with your secret key (see cloud code in link below)
7. Google will verify the token, the response will indicate if the token is valid or invalid.

Refer to the following post where I have included the cloud cloud you will require on the server side. [Parse.Com - HTTP method in cloud code, how do I wait for the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554682/parse-com-http-method-in-cloud-code-how-do-i-wait-for-the-response).  Super easy to set up.

Comment: The cloud code is only run if you call it in your page/app that you yourself made. But someone can still by-pass the cloud code by making their own page, using your API keys and just start to fill-up the database with fake users?

Comment: That is not correct, did you review documentation?, you are forgetting that you need to send the Google recaptcha token as part of the Parse signup process, (steps above), the token is used on server side to authenticate to google with your secret key before user is saved. Recaptcha only works for registered domain and localhost. You could use localhost to fill up a database full of fake users but this would be a very time consuming manual process, and recaptcha would detect multiple 'I am a human' attempts from the same host and will make the user go through additional verification checks.

Comment: I really thank you for your help and time, but I don;t think you understood me. I'm saying that anyone can **make their own page** and keep adding users with that, after they get the API keys from app / website. I've edited the question with the code you can try out. It doesnt call the cloud code, therefore it wont check recaptcha or anything? The above page you dont have to run from server, just run from desktop.

Comment: I do not see any recaptcha code in your example. You need to add the recaptcha to your page, refer to the Google documentation or look for examples on the web.  The recapatcha is linked to your domain (point 1 above),  the user has to go through the recapatcha to obtain the token (point 3) which you then pass to Parse during the User signUp (point 5), and then in the cloud code, apply your token key + secret key and make a call to google (point 6), based on the response from Google, you either permit the user to be created or not.